# Calculating with a SVG elipitical arc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I'm working on a custom pyQt SVG renderer and need help. This is purely mathematical so you won't need an API.

To calculate a SVG elliptical arc you need two radii `rx` and `ry`; the rotation of the ellipse in degrees `x-axis-rotation`; the `large-arc-sweep-flag` (1 or 0) that determines if an arc is drawn through greater than or less than 180 degrees and the direction of the arc around the circle; the `sweep-flag` (1 or 0) determines if the arc will be drawn in a negative or positive direction; and the final `x` and `y` values determine the end of the arc.

However, `QPainterPath.arcTo(self, float x, float y, float w, float h, float startAngle, float arcLenght)` uses a bounding rectangle `x, y, w, h`; a starting angle `startAngle`; and an arcLength/sweepLength the length of the arc itself. How do I translate the SVG command to something the `arcTo()` method can use?

Sources:
[W3C SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands),
[QPainterPath](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qpainterpath.html#arcTo)

Answer (score 1):

SVG elliptical arcs use "endpoint parametrization".

`QPainterPath.arcTo` arcs use "center parametrization".

The SVG link you kindly provided has a link near the end of the section entitled 
["Elliptical arc implementation notes"](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ArcImplementationNotes) which gives [formulas for the conversion](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ArcConversionEndpointToCenter) between endpoint and center parametrization.

---

Note that the [QPainterPath.arcTo documentation](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qpainterpath.html#arcTo-2) states that the call signature is

```
QPainterPath.arcTo (self, QRectF rect, float startAngle, float arcLength)
```

but instead of `arcLength` its description refers to `sweepLength`:

> Creates an arc that occupies the given rectangle, beginning at the
>   specified startAngle and extending sweepLength degrees
>   counter-clockwise.

Oddly, it says that `sweepLength` is measured in degrees, while arclength has a conventional mathematical meaning which is always a distance.

Even though the documentation uses the confusing parameter name "arclength" I think it meant to say that the last argument to `arcTo` is the sweep angle, Δθ.

So if you use the formulas from the SVG implementation notes for 
θ1, Δθ I think they can be used for `startAngle` and `arcLength`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I made it past basic algebra and trigonometry but this is a little hard to understand. The bounding rect `x = w - rx`, `y = h - ry`, `w = rx * 2`, `h = ry * 2`. Hopefully figuring out `startAngle` and `arcLength` are next.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm just going to ask someone how to translate those equations into python, but thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.