# SVG path with rounded corners as arcs of a circle

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, curve, elliptic-curve, geometric-arc

I need to create SVG paths with rounded corners to export them to DXF for cutting. My problem is that the corners should be arcs of a circle, not some bezier curve.

Its relatively easy with right angles using the `arc` command because the radius is also the distance from the corner to where the arc begins. With other angles it is way more complicated.

Is there a formula to calculate the start and end point of the arc given a corner and a radius?

[image]

The upper right corner is easy but the lower left is very tricky because I have to find out where the line has to end and the arc begins.

I've found [calculationg with a svg eliptical arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691419/calculating-with-a-svg-elipitical-arc), which links a formula to convert end-point to center parametrization. Which doesn't help because I also don't know where the center of the circle has to be.

[How to calculate the SVG Path for an arc (of a circle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736398/how-to-calculate-the-svg-path-for-an-arc-of-a-circle) just calculates the arc, not an arc between two lines replacing a sharp corner.

The solutions in [Rounded corners on triangle in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659423/rounded-corners-on-triangle-in-svg) work only when some sides are parallel to the coordinate system or change the radius.

[Applying rounded corners to paths/polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269622/applying-rounded-corners-to-paths-polygons) tries to use some tricks with linejoin or several cubic curves, nothing I want.

Even Inkscape (which I used to draw the image above) uses 5 cubic curves instead of an arc even when I used a circle to create this shape.

If you have some hints how I can manage this I would be very grateful.

Comment: Browsers generally implement arc drawing via one or more Beziers so even if you work out the right arc to draw it won't change anything.

Comment: It does change things for me because the SVG I generate is not only displayed in the browser but later exported to DXF for cutting or plotting. And here it is important to have a chamfered corner with constant corner radius.

Comment: How would you define a rounded corner for not-right angles using Beziers so you don't have deviation from a circular arc? Is there an algorithm for calculating the control points? I would like to have only one arc/curve in the corner so the path doesn't get too complicated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The geometry of a chamfered corner looks like this:

[image: geometry of a chamfered corner]

Angle **ABC** is equal to *θ* (the outside angle of the chamfered corner). This is bisected by **BD**, so angle **DBC** is equal to *θ*/2. That means the offset distance *d* from the corner to points **C** and **A** is equal to *r* × tan(*θ*/2).

For a right angle, *θ*=90° and tan(*θ*/2)=1, so *d* is equal to *r*.

As Robert Longson said, you would be lucky to find an SVG application that exports chamfered corners using circular arc segments. However, with a bit of effort, it should be possible to detect and convert them programmatically.

Comment: That looks very promising, thank you. I have to export the path to DXF later to cut out things or plot them so it is relevant to me. Works great with right angles already and I want to allow other angles too.

Comment: Update: Works great.
`Math.abs(radius * Math.tan((180-angle)/2)` if you have the angle of the corner and the radius.

Comment: @Dehalion, I would be curious to see your final code for the chamfering of SVG paths if it's easily extractable from your program. I have a similar problem where I need to programmatically generate rounded corners for a laser cutting-pattern with non-right angles.

Comment: @Hypher I'm preparing a blog post on this, please hold on a bit :D